# The hermitian element $h=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{p_{n}}{3^{n}}$ generates $C_{0}(\Omega)$‎

Tags: operator-theory, banach-algebras

‎Please help me to solve the following problem‎ :

Let $\Omega$ be a locally compact Hausdorff space‎, ‎and suppose that the $C^{*}$-algebra   $C_{0}(\Omega)$ is generated by a sequence of projections $(p_{n})_{n=1}^\infty$‎.

Then the hermitian element $h=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{p_{n}}{3^{n}}$ generates $C_{0}(\Omega)$‎

Comment: An ‎element ‎‎$‎a‎\in A‎$ is hermitian or self-adjoint if ‎$‎a=‎a‎‎^{‎*‎}‎$‎‎

Comment: ‎$C_{0}(X)=\{f\in C(X)~|~f~vanishes~at~infinity \}$

Comment: Can you pose this as a question?